# iPhone5 Button Placement using IF statement?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a game whereby the button for pause is supposed to be on the top right hand corner, however on iPhone 5 it is 3/4 way up the top, so I tried to manually set it but I cannot get it to work, this works, however on the iPhone 3 & 4 it does not show (so it's obviously ignoring some part of the IF statement)

```
CCMenuItemSprite* item1 = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[[MainInfo shareInstance] getImageName:@"pause1.png"]]
                                                      selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[[MainInfo shareInstance] getImageName:@"pause2.png"]]
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(soundOff)];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, nil];

    if ( ![[MainInfo shareInstance] isIPad] )
        menu.position = ccp(290, 450); //450 iPhone3/4
//  else

        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            // do something specific for iPhone 5
            menu.position = ccp(290, 530); //450 iPhone3/4

        }else

     menu.position = ccp(696, 960);

    [_bottomFrame addChild:menu z:30 tag:1234];

    [self updateBoard];
}
```

At the top of the .m file I have the following;

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
```

Could anyone please help with a correct way to write the code above?

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: Yikes... Umm. If you could please format that code a little better, that would be great, it is very confusing right now. For example, why do you have `if (IS_IPHONE_5) {...}else` and no brackets after that? Why do you have a random `//  else` in your code? With a little clarity this could be a very good question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just as an FYI for future reference here, and for if you work on a team, it is a good idea to *not* double space your code. It makes it a little hard to follow. Only skip a line to show for example a different action, or a different group, but other than that, try to keep your code condensed.

Comment: have  a look at my answer

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the iPhone 5 code, does it get hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ELSE statment is not enclosed in brackets furthoremore:

```
 CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
    /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/
} else {
    /*Do iPhone Classic stuff here.*/
}
```